# Flutter tabs - a tab is created even though it's not displayed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `DefaultTabController` containing a `TabBarView` with a `TabController`, so far nothing special.

I have 1 tab which needs to make a request to the server as soon as it's initialized, let's call it the explore tab.

I'm making the request in `didChangeDependencies` if it wasn't already initialized (I have a boolean flag for initialized).

It's indeed making a request everytime the tab's widget is created, however there's one problem.

Let's say there are 3 tabs, while the explore tab is the second tab in between 1 and 3.

When going from tab 1 to tab 3, or from tab 3 to tab 1, it seems that the explore tab is created during the transition (even though it's not displayed at all), and a request to the server is consequently made.

I'd like to avoid that and only make that request in the explore tab's didChangeDependencies when the user is specifically going to the explore tab.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, you have 3 tabs

[tab1],[tab2],[tab3]

Where you would like to triger an event (request to the server) only when [tab2] was pressed.

To achieve this, create a `tabController` isolated to add an event listener in a StateFull widget, example:

```
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      if (_tabController.indexIsChanging == false) {
        if(_tabController.index == 1) { 
          //Trigger your request
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Note: `indexIsChanging == false`  is to ensure that tab already finished the job of change currentIndex of that controller, full example below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BodyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BodyWidgetState createState() {
    return new BodyWidgetState();
  }
}

class BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      if (_tabController.indexIsChanging == false) {
        if (_tabController.index == 1) {
          //Trigger your request
          print('Triger 2 selected, do the http call now.');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
            Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
            Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(child: Center(child: Text('tab1'))),
          Container(child: Center(child: Text('tab2'))),
          Container(child: Center(child: Text('tab3'))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Can you help-me giving the bounty points? Thanks! :D

Comment: Sure, just had to wait for it to be enabled.